# TikZ: How to draw an optical encoder wheel?

Tags: tikz-pgf

im trying to make my own homemade optical encoder in order to be able to control some of it paramter such like inner and outer radius and the number of wheel marks. I want it to look some like this:

[image: Optical Encoder Wheel]

and this is what i have done so far:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{forloop}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\innerRadius}
\setlength{\innerRadius}{3mm}
\newlength{\outerRadius}
\setlength{\outerRadius}{4mm}

\newcounter{loops}
\setcounter{loops}{4}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (c1) at (0,0);
  \draw[fill=black] (c1) circle (.005cm);
  \draw (c1) circle (\innerRadius);
  \draw (c1) circle (\outerRadius);
  \foreach \i in {1,...,loops}
  {
       %\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\angle}{45*\i}
       \draw[fill=black] ($(c1) + (0:\innerRadius)$) arc (0:45:\innerRadius) -- ($(c1) + (45:\outerRadius)$) arc (45:0:\outerRadius) -- cycle;
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

i can't achieve to draw each mark depending on the number specified by "loops" variable because the pgfmath function throws me an error and i cant realize why.

is there any way to draw this encoder wheel? Thanks.

Comment: The counter value is available as `\value{loops}`: `\foreach \i in {1, ..., \value{loops}}`

Comment: Thanks a lot Heiko, it worked perfectly now! (also learned a few new things about latex)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\innerRadius{30mm}
  \def\outerRadius{40mm}
  \def\wheelMarks{50}
  \def\cRadius{2mm}
  \def\cLen{8mm}
  \coordinate (c1) at (0, 0);

  % Wheel markings
  \fill
    let \n0={360/\wheelMarks} in
      \foreach \i in {1, ..., \wheelMarks} {
        let \n1={\i*\n0} in
          (c1) -- (\n1:\outerRadius)
          arc(\n1:\n1 + \n0/2:\outerRadius)
          -- ($(c1) + (\n1 + \n0/2:\innerRadius)$)
          arc(\n1 + \n0/2:\n1:\innerRadius)
          -- cycle
    }
  ;

  \draw
    % Wheel circles
    (c1) circle[radius=\outerRadius]
         circle[radius=\innerRadius]
    % Center markings with circle and cross
         circle[radius=\cRadius]
    ($(c1) - (\cLen, 0)$) -- ++(2*\cLen, 0)
    ($(c1) - (0, \cLen)$) -- ++(0, 2*\cLen)
  ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: A brief digression: is there a technical difference between using `\def` and `\newlength` to declare a new length?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou Several differences.

Comment: @egreg OP used `\newlength` while @Heiko used `\def` instead. So, I wondered why he didn't follow the same approach of declaring variables in the question body.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou Those lengths are more like parameters, so it's not necessary to waste a length register just for them; length registers are needed when you want to operate on those dimensions.

Answer (score 9):

another solution to make absolute encoder

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Ra}{4}

\foreach \nb in {0,1,2,3,4,5}{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Rext}{\Ra+\nb*0.8}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Rint}{\Rext-0.8}
\draw (0,0) circle (\Rext);
\pgfmathsetmacro{\nbfentes}{2^\nb}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\pas}{180/\nbfentes}
\foreach \aa in {1,...,\nbfentes}{
\draw[fill,rotate=2*\aa*\pas] (0:\Rint) -- (0:\Rext) arc (0:\pas:\Rext) -- (\pas:\Rint ) arc (\pas:0:\Rint);
}
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Now for a Gray code pattern...

Comment: its more difficult

Answer (score 7):

Another solution is to use dashed circle in place of a loop.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}

\begin{document}
  % parameters to set
  \def\minR{3}
  \def\maxR{4}
  \def\numMarks{50}
  % some calculations
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\midR}{(\minR+\maxR)/2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\dR}{\maxR-\minR}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\dM}{2*pi*\midR/(2*\numMarks)}
  % the picture
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw circle(\minR/4) (-\minR/2,0) -- (\minR/2,0)  (0,-\minR/2) -- (0,\minR/2);
    \draw circle(\minR) circle(\maxR);
    \draw[line width=\dR cm,dash pattern=on \dM cm off \dM cm] circle(\midR);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for a clever variant. I am frequently astonished, how many problems one can solve by just a clever fill or line pattern!

Answer (score 7):

Solution for a Gray code pattern after adapting **rpapa**'s solution. Several parameters allow some customization.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

% Create a real Gray encoder
% By v.santos, 2020.

% Based on code from:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326792/tikz-how-to-draw-an-optical-encoder-wheel

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Ra}{2.5}          %Minimal internal radius
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Th}{0.5}          %Crown thickness
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Nbits}{8}         %Number of bits (2 or more)

\pgfmathsetmacro{\xtraOffset}{0}    %Optional initial angular offset
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Cbits}{\Nbits-1}  %Aux variable to index bits starting on 0 of up to \Nbits-1

\foreach \nb in {0,1,...,\Cbits}
{
%Useful variables inside the loop
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Rext}{\Ra+\nb*\Th}      %external radius of circular crown
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Rint}{\Rext-\Th}        %internal radius of circular crown
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\nsectors}{max(2,2^\nb)} %number of sectors of current crown (0th and 1st have both two sectors)
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\step}{360/\nsectors}    %angular step in current crown

    \ifthenelse{\nb=0}                                    %different offset for first crown
        {\pgfmathsetmacro{\offset}{180+\xtraOffset}}      %offset in first crown
        {\pgfmathsetmacro{\offset}{\step/2+\xtraOffset}}  %offset in other crowns

%The black "bits" (sectors) around the circular crowns
    \foreach \aa in {1,...,\nsectors}
    {
        \draw[line width=0,fill,rotate=2*\aa*\step+\offset] (0:\Rint) -- (0:\Rext) arc (0:\step:\Rext) -- (\step:\Rint ) arc (\step:0:\Rint); %draw each black "bit"
    }
}

%% Below follow additional complementary illustrative elements.
%% May be omitted if only the rotary encoder is needed.

%The delimiting circles 
\foreach \nb in {-1,0,1,...,\Cbits}  %start in -1 to draw first inner circle as well
{
    \draw [gray,ultra thin](0,0) circle (\Ra+\nb*\Th);
    %Comment previous line if you do not need to draw delimiting circles
}

%The delimiting radial lines
\pgfmathsetmacro{\nblines}{2^(\Nbits}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\OuterR}{\Ra+\Cbits*\Th}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ang}{360/\nblines}
\foreach \aa in {1,...,\nblines}
{
       \draw [ultra thin,gray,rotate=\aa*\ang+\xtraOffset] (0,0) -- (0:\OuterR);
       %Comment previous line if you do not need to draw radial lines
}

%Plot readings along the transitions to illustrate the advantages of Gray codes
%With a diameter small enough, only one black/white transition occurs at once!
%Diameter may need to be much smaller for many bits
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Tline}{16}         %Set any number from 1 to \nblines
%\foreach \Tline in {1,...,\nblines} %or uncomment this to draw all readings (many!!!)
%\foreach \Tline in {1,2}            % ... or alternatively two draw a limited number of reading lines
\foreach \nb in {0,1,...,\Cbits} 
{
    \draw [very thin,red,fill,rotate=(\Tline-1)*\ang+\xtraOffset] (\Ra-\Th/2+\nb*\Th,0) circle (\Th/8); %You may want to adapt the diameter of circle for better visualization
}

\path (0,0) -- ++(0,-\OuterR-0.5) node () {Gray code shaft encoder with \Nbits{} bits};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote, can be used.

The number of rings is determined by `\n`. The number of slices in each ring is `2^\i` (where `\i` goes from 1 till `\n`) and this is passed to the key `total count`.

In the key `slices style` we use `\WClistcolors` which refers to items in the list given to the key `WClistcolors`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\n{7}
\foreach\i in {1,...,\n}{
  \wheelchart[
    radius={\i+1}{\i+2},
    slices style={
      \WClistcolors,
      draw=gray,
      ultra thick
    },
    start half=0,
    total count=2^\i,
    WClistcolors={white,black}
  ]{}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```